# Grab remote images and update links in existing posts

Tags: images

I have a blog that's been migrated from Typepad to Wordpress, but all of the image links still link to Typepad, and the images are still located there.  Is there a plugin available for 3.3.2 that will crawl through those posts, identify image links that aren't hosted locally, then grab a copy and update the link?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the plugin Cache Images works very well for this. You can scan your entire site and bring over all the images so they're local:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/

You may want to install Smush.it before you bring over your images if you want to reduce their file size at the same time you make the transfer.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/

I'm not sure what you mean by "images still link to Typepad" though. If you mean the images themselves are hyperlinked to point at posts hosted on Typepad, you'll need to do a database search/replace to fix that. This is a really good tool for that: http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: The images links go to, say, http://blog.typepad.com/image.  I'm hoping to find a plugin that will download that image, and then update the link to the version located in the media library.

Comment: Then Cache Images should work. Try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It found all the image links and ran through the caching process, but nothing showed up in my media library and no links were updated.